# Ansible include tasklist with become

Tags: ansible

I want to execute a certain list of tasks (within a role in a playbook) in ansible as a specific user.  The user will actually come from a variable, but in the minimal example I'm hard-codi ng it to "dev".  (This user does exist).  I can't work out why the following doesn't work

My main.yml in the roles/foo/tasks is

```
- include_tasks: "{{ role_path }}/tasks/content.yml"
  become: yes
  become_user: dev
```

While the content.yml just fetches the current user:

```
- command: whoami
  register: whoami
- debug:
    var: whoami
```

My playbook is

```
- hosts: dev
  become: true
  remote_user: root  
  roles:
    - foo
```

I am getting the following output:

```
PLAY [dev] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [adco-test-webdev]

TASK [foo : include_tasks] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
included: /smbshare/ansible/roles/foo/tasks/content.yml for adco-test-webdev

TASK [foo : command] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [adco-test-webdev]

TASK [foo : debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [adco-test-webdev] => {
    "whoami": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": [
            "whoami"
        ],
        "delta": "0:00:00.002194",
        "end": "2018-07-25 02:05:54.879601",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2018-07-25 02:05:54.877407",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "root",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "root"
        ]
    }
}
```

Why is it giving the user as root?  I know I connect as root, but I then become dev for the includes don't I?

If this is how it's meant to work, then how should I configure a role so that a whole list of tasks are run as a certain user? DO I have to remember the become and become_user on every item?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `import_tasks` instead of `include_tasks`:

```
- import_tasks: "{{ role_path }}/tasks/content.yml"
  become: yes
  become_user: dev
```

---

In future versions (starting with 2.7) you will be able to do it with the a new parameter `apply`:

```
- include_tasks: "{{ role_path }}/tasks/content.yml"
  args:
    apply:
      become: yes
      become_user: dev
```

Comment: That seems to work - at least for this example, I need to test my more complex real case.  But why?  According to the docs "All `import*` statements are pre-processed at the time playbooks are parsed." while "All `include*` statements are processed as they encountered during the execution of the playbook."  Since I am actually becoming a user from a variable which is processed with `combine` I assumed I wanted the dynamic one

Comment: Because someone who implemented or maintains the `include_tasks` module did not implement the feature of inheriting the `become` settings by the included tasks, before you came up with this question. But [implemented it for future version 2.7](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/2c9cbae3f9fe289e77168efdbcc8ee4b4547b931/lib/ansible/modules/utilities/logic/include_tasks.py#L31)

Comment: Thanks!  Reading further it does say "For static imports, the parent task options will be copied to all child tasks contained within the import. For dynamic includes, the task options will only apply to the dynamic task as it is evaluated, and will not be copied to child tasks." but it seems a bit counter-intuitive that a static import has the (dynamically set) become applied while the dynamic import doesn't :)